# what does 'o' means in the instance method argument?

Tags: objective-c, ios

New to objective-c,

```
-(void) myfunction : (int) d
```

It means that returning 'void' and take single parameter of type int.

what does  the following mean ?

```
-(void) myfunction:o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it translates to

```
- (void) myfunction:(id) o
```

For example, the method

```
-(void) myfunction:o:p:q {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", o,p,q);
}
```

When called with

```
[self myfunction:@"test" :[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] :nil];
```

Prints out:

```
2012-04-14 08:02:20.470 Test[36499:f803] test, 4, (null)
```

Comment: So, if i provide like:  -(void) myfunction:o second:m third:n, will be equivalent to -(void) myfumction: (id)o second: (id) m third: (id)n  ?

Comment: you got it.  I wouldn't recommend doing that as it kind of makes code harder to read and confusing for some.

Answer (score -1):

**Both are same**

In objective-c first parameter name is consider as function name